# What is the right way to determine, in CGo, if the environment supports AVX-512?

Tags: x86-64, avx, cgo, avx512

CGo appears to be removing preprocessor definitions.  Has anyone else run into this?

In my other C code on the same machine, this works fine.  In CGo, the "__AVX2__" definition gets removed.

I've tried this with and without the '-march=native'

How can I get it back ?

The code:

```
    //go:build amd64 && !purego && gc
    // +build amd64,!purego,gc

    // #cgo CFLAGS: -march=native

    package keccakAVX512

    /*
    // check if the amd64 machine supports AVX512 instructions at build time and call
    // an assembly function using AVX512 if so.


    #ifdef __AVX2__
        void keccakF1600_AVX512(unsigned long* state);

    this should fail with a syntax error but doesn't
    #endif

    //      void keccakF1600_AVX512(unsigned long* state) {};
    */
    import "C"

    func KeccakF1600AMDAVX512(a *[25]uint64) {
        C.keccakF1600_AVX512((*C.ulong)(&a[0]))
    }
```

With the 'go tool cgo' command, I see that the default '-m64' is taking precedence, even with the CFLAGS set.

Comment: IDK about CGo, but for normal GCC or clang, `-m64` is orthogonal to `-march=native`.  `-m64` just means to make 64-bit code (vs. `-m32` 32-bit code, or `-mx32` ILP32 code in 64-bit mode).  Disabling ISA extensions would be `-march=x86-64` (i.e. baseline for the ISA, just SSE2).

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was in the #cgo syntax.  It has to be inside the '/**/' comment block instead of the '//' comment block.

```
package keccakAVX512

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -march=native
// check if the amd64 machine supports AVX512 instructions at build time and call
// an assembly function using AVX512 if so.

#ifdef __AVX2__
void keccakF1600_AVX512(unsigned long* state);

#else

void keccakF1600_AVX512(unsigned long* state) {};
#endif
*/
import "C"

func KeccakF1600AMDAVX512(a *[25]uint64) {
    C.keccakF1600_AVX512((*C.ulong)(&a[0]))
}
```